# Immutable struct with collection

Tags: .net, struct, collections, immutability

I'm making an immutable struct in .Net which contains a read only collection of a different immutable struct (I have full control over the entire design).  I don't need a non-mutating Add method.

What's the best way to do that?

I could make the outer struct have a reference to a `ReadOnlyCollection` containing the inner struct.  Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadOnlyCollection` is one way.

Depending on what you need to do with the collection, you could also expose it as `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: +1 You could use an simple array, but array are mutable. The `Array` class has a static method called `AsReadOnly` that converts arrays to read-only collections. It returns a `ReadOnlyCollection`. There's no reason to differ from that.

Comment: @jpbochi: Depending upon what one is doing, it may be better to use an array, but not store a reference to it in any field until it's been completely filled in, and neither modify the array nor expose it to any code that might modify it, but instead only allow access to the array contents via the struct's methods or properties.  This approach would have less overhead than using a ReadOnlyCollection wrapper, but would have the disadvantage that of not being able to supply users of the class with something they could use to access the array without going through the struct.  A third approach...

Comment: ...might be to have the struct keep an `IList` which would initially be assigned to an array, but which could be replaced by a `ReadOnlyCollection` if one was requested.  This would in many cases allow repeated requests for a collection reference to be satisfied with the same `ReadOnlyCollection` instance, but with the caveat that if a read-only struct instance is asked for a `ReadOnlyCollection` it would be unable to cache the reference.

Comment: @supercat: One thing is certain, exposing an `Array` is a bad thing. It's always better to expose an `IEnumerable`, an `ICollection`, or an `IList`.

Comment: @supercat: Another bad thing is letting other components modify your collection directly when you don't want that. One approach to achieve that is by exposing a read-only collection. Another approach is by always providing a copy of the real collection. Which approach is better depends on the likeness of your collection changing. And, of course, if performance is a priority, you can just expose your internal collection and trust that nobody will mess with it. Do you agree?

Comment: @jpbochi: I've written some classes with a property `ArrayAsReadOnly`.  Because some of the code which uses the property will pass it to methods which need an array, and because copying the array all the time would be expensive, the property does expose the array itself (potentially lazily creating it) but rely upon the classes that use it (all of which, at least for now, were written by me) not to mess with it.  As it happens, the arrays in question are not what the class uses to actually store its data; most updates will cause the class to invalidate its...

Comment: ...array references, and recompute the arrays the next time they're requested. There may be hundreds of requests for the same array between updates, so returning the same array instance is helpful.  If `Array` inherited from `ReadableArray`, which also had child `ImmutableArray` (whose constructor could either take a `ReadableArray`, an `IEnumerable<T>`, or lists of initialization contents and ranges, and if routines that just needed to read an array were written to accept the base type rather than `Array`, then I would probably have used `ImmutableArray`. As no such pattern exists in .net ...

Comment: ...the best I can really do is rely upon the caller to refrain from writing the array.  Having the class return a new defensively-copied array instance with each call would be icky.  Having the caller pass in a `List<T>` (the size is variable) would be decent semantically, but bad from a performance standpoint.  Wrapping the thing in a `ReadOnlyCollection` and forcing callers to copy it to an array so they can pass it to code that wants an array but isn't going to modify it is clunky and slow.  I really wish .net had included an immutable array type--that would have been clean.

Comment: (Actually, thinking about it, even having a caller pass in a List<T> wouldn't be great, since the caller would still have to copy the contents to an array in order to pass them to any of the framework methods that require arrays.  I wonder what "the next popular framework" will be, and if it will include a proper immutable-array type?

Comment: I'm not sure I followed all your reasoning. What framework methods require arrays? This is not a good thing to do, specially on API's.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15487/discussion-between-jpbochi-and-supercat)